# Opera adds weird spacing in documents with contenteditable and twitter bootstrap, why?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, opera, contenteditable

Opera seems to add some weird vertical spaces between certain document elements when using [contenteditable](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#contenteditable) together with [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

**JSFiddle examples:**

[Contenteditable not enabled](http://jsfiddle.net/RVXdj/) vs [Contenteditable enabled](http://jsfiddle.net/wUuSn/) - note that in the first example, the rows have no vertical spacing between them, but in the second, they do.

Tested in Opera 11.61 on Linux and 11.62 on Windows. In any other browser I tested, the rows had no vertical spacing between them in either of the fiddles.

I tried removing bootstrap and adding [the css it applies](http://pastie.org/3852892) manually, but that did not trigger the margin. However, when inspecting the DOM, I found some weird `<::before>` and `<::after>` tags that I suspect to be related ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr9VB.png)).

What does the bootstrap css do to make this happen, and what is the best approach to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nixing these selectors removes the spacing:

```
.row:before,.row:after{display:table;content:"";}
.row:after{clear:both;}
```

No idea what it controls, or why you need it. Looks to be some sort of clearfix type thing, but I don't know. http://jsfiddle.net/wUuSn/2/